# Why do unbuffered read()/write() operations use buffer cache?

Tags: c, unix, io

Basically on UNIX, `read()` and `write()` functions are unbuffered I/O,

and there are Standard I/O, which is buffered I/O.

But, `read()` and `write()` functions use *buffer cache* which is in kernel before doing real I/O(I/O to real device), and real I/O happens using *buffer cache*. It's using buffer.

I heard unbuffered I/O means I/O happens on char-by-char to real device.

Then, why `read()` and `write()` functions are unbuffered I/O, even though it is using *buffer cache*?

Comment: SUSv4 does not specify that `read` and `write` must be unbuffered: [read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html), [write](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html)

Comment: Where did you get the notion that `read()` and `write()` are unbuffered?

Comment: Additionally, the `sync` call ([sync](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sync.html)) exists for a reason.

Comment: The book *advanced programming in the unix environment* shows the title 'unbuffered i/o'

Comment: @A.Cho That only means that `read()` and `write()` are not *necessarily* buffered. At least in Linux they are buffered by default unless `O_DIRECT` is specified; I can't speak to BSD or other Unices.

Comment: "I heard unbuffered I/O means I/O happens on char-by-char to real device.", it depends on the device, you have two kinds of devices under Unix: char-oriented and -block-oriented. In general, disks are used through block-oriented drivers (even if there also exists a char-oriented access to).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the term "buffering" here means "a place where data is stored when going to/from the kernel", i.e. to avoid doing one system call for each I/O call, the buffered functions use a buffer between.

What the kernel does with the data is not something the standard library can do much about.

It would be possible to do a 1:1 mapping of read/write calls at the standard library's level (i.e. `fread()` and friends) to `read()`/`write()` calls on the underlying file descriptor; the term buffering is telling you that is *not* what you can expect.

Answer (score 1):

"(Un)buffered" in the manual refers to user-space buffering. Kernel space buffering depends on implementation, usually most devices are buffered (disk, sockets, USB etc.) except hardware ports (GPIO).